# Make a request in native Fetch with Proxy in NodeJS 18

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

In version 18 of Node JS there is already the possibility of making request Fetch without installing packages (example: Axios).

My question is if you can make a request to this Native Fetch **with Proxy without installing packages** or do you have to install packages to use a Proxy in Fetch?

In case I have to install a package to use Proxy in Fetch, what would be the best one to use with Node's new Fetch?

I really appreciate it if you can leave an implementation code, thanks!

Comment: you can use `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variable here too,( i think )

Comment: I have tried many npm proxies and none have worked with native fetch. It is very frustrating to find a working proxy.

Comment: then you may want to take a look at this `HttpAgent` implementation and try to implement a light version of it in your code (its using node http lib to implement an proxy agent, no external thing there) if you don't wan't to use any external library. here: `https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-http-proxy-agent/blob/master/src/agent.ts`. and take a look at the example in the readme so you get some idea how to use it

Comment: @ben: Those environment variables are not yet supported, see [this issue](https://github.com/nodejs/undici/issues/1650).

Answer (score 8):

I got proxies to work with native `fetch()`, but I did have to install a package (this is because they haven't exposed the functionality to set the proxy nativly, see [this issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/43187) mentioned in the other answer). This answer might also be useful to those looking to set a proxy server for existing packages that use native `fetch()` (in my case, Octokit).

I couldn't get it to accept the certificate it presented, as it was signed with an internal Root CA and returned an error `Error: self-signed certificate in certificate chain` (`SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN`). I tried setting the env var `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` to a file with the required root CA, to no avail. I also tried specifying `{rejectUnauthorized: false}` in both the `ProxyAgent` ctor and the options for the fetch itself, but it didn't have any effect. So I decided to set the env var `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED`. If anyone knows how to get custom root CAs to work with native `fetch()` and proxies, please contribute.

After installing the `undici` NPM package (via `npm install undici` or `yarn add undici`), use the following to grab the proxy config from the `https_proxy` env var:

```js
import { env } from "process";
import { setGlobalDispatcher, ProxyAgent } from "undici";

if (env.https_proxy) {
  // Corporate proxy uses CA not in undici's certificate store
  process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
  const dispatcher = new ProxyAgent({uri: new URL(env.https_proxy).toString() });
  setGlobalDispatcher(dispatcher);
}

await fetch("https://www.stackoverflow.com");
```

Comment: It appears this is the officially recommended method AFAICT - https://github.com/nodejs/undici/issues/1350. Especially now that Node Fetch is considered stable in Node 21: https://nodejs.org/en/blog/announcements/v21-release-announce but doesn't include Proxy/Agent support, I'm guessing they're trying to keep fetch a minimal implementation and the use of proxies as an expanded bit of functionality.

Answer (score 4):

Node 18 does not support proxies with native fetch yet (https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/42814), but it is being worked on https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/43187. It does not appear to have been implemented in time for Node 20.

Edit: Now with Node 20 released, this is working for us. Though it does use node's new fetch, it isn't quite what you asked for as it also requires an import of `undici` to support the proxy. But as `undici` is also developed by Node maintainers and inspired Node's native fetch implementation, maybe this is close enough.

```
import { ProxyAgent } from 'undici'
const dispatcher = new ProxyAgent('https://proxy.com')


const r = await fetch('google.com', { 
         dispatcher,
         method: 'POST',
         body: JSON.stringify({ hi: "mom" })
})
```