# HTTP_PROXY env in docker container of nodejs not working

Tags: node.js, docker, environment-variables, fetch-api, http-proxy

I have a nodejs application docker image and I have set HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY according to the instructions on the [Docker website](https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/). However, when my nodejs application uses 'await fetch', it does not use my proxy by default.

Node.js App Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT ["node"]

CMD ["index.mjs"]
```

index.mjs

```js
// Node.js version: v20.3.1

async function main() {
    const response = await fetch('test.com')
    // HTTP_PROXY IS NOT USED !!! QAQ
    return response.text()
}

main().then(console.log)
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
services:
    app:
        networks:
            - proxy.network
        ports:
            - '8080:80'
        environment:
            - HTTP_PORT=80
            - HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.server:1081
            - HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy.server:1081
            - NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,*.server

networks:
    proxy.network:
        external: true
        name: proxy.network
```

I have tried setting various environment variables in docker run:
HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY, http_proxy, https_proxy, etc.,
but fetchAPI in container does not use them by default.

I want to make the fetchAPI in my nodejs application docker container use the HTTP_PROXY proxy specified in the docker run environment variables by default.

Comment: Could you even try this solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76503362/5952279 ?

Comment: @VasylMoskalov yes,  but this solution not includes NO_PROXY and need to include "undici" manally.